# Wireless on an Atheros AR9285 is slow and disconnects

Tags: wireless, drivers, atheros

I installed Ubuntu on my notebook yesterday. All right except wi-fi connection.

I found wi-fi network (based on D-link dir-300) and connected. But it works too slow and disconnect every 1-3 minutes. You can say that maybe problem is in connection but on my notebook i have windows 7 and ubuntu 10.10 and in windows i have no such problem. Windows works well with wi-fi. But Ubuntu...

I have:

> DSL internet connection. modem is
> connected to router. Router connected
> with desktop by wire and with notebook
> samsung R528 by wifi. Router - D-link
> DIR-300.

Rusult of lspci -k is:

```
Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device e025
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
```

Thanks for any help!

P.S.

> I wrote this message from Windows 7. I
> edited this message from Ubuntu but i
> see that internet works more slower
> than in Windows 7.
>
> Firefox on Winddows 7 loads this page in ~ 2-3 seconds
> Firefox on Ubuntu 10.10 loads this page in ~ 20 seconds

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/29950/edit) your post to include the output of `lspci -k`. This is almost certainly a driver issue but until we know what hardware we're actually dealing with, we can't help.

Comment: Having said that, I've just realised your plight: How could you edit this post from Ubuntu without network connectivity? If you run `lspci -k > ~/Desktop/keep-this-file` in Ubuntu and then copy the file it generates to something like an external disk and then read and post that to here from Windows, that should work.

Comment: i edited my post!

Comment: Look at the output of `iwconfig`. It should give you (among other things), things like transmission power, signal level, noise level etc. It may tell you whether your incoming signal levels are too weak or your transmission power is small.

Answer (score 3):

Kernel 2.6.39 completely fixed the issues with the ath9x driver for me in 11.04 (Natty). I can do high-load transfers without issue. [Comment #8 on "wlan (AR928X, ath9k) slow since upgrade to natty"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/761176) contains instructions on how to get this kernel from a PPA. I did an `apt-get install` rather than a `dist-upgrade`, but either one should get you the new kernel. Here's what I did:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kernel-ppa/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install linux-generic-pae
```

If you're using a 64-bit kernel, I think the package to install is just "linux-generic". Or just follow the instructions right in the bug (use `apt-get dist-upgrade -y`).

Also possibly related:

- [UNR Ath9K unstable connection](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/378156)

After upgrading to linux 2.6.39, changing the ath9k driver config (as suggested in [Why is my internet so slow with an Atheros wireless card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37409/why-is-my-internet-so-slow-with-an-atheros-wireless-card/40692#40692)) is not necessary.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have to say that on linux version 3.0.0-12-generic this problem still persists. Solution described on http://askubuntu.com/questions/37409/why-is-my-internet-so-slow-with-an-atheros-wireless-card/40692#40692 worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have been having this issue with Atheros for a long, long time. I have even given up on Ubuntu for some time (my Windows connection worked fine), but I found out that switching from Unity to Gnome was enough to solve the problem. I don't know how to explain why this is so (new user), but it just works.

Maybe you want to check the question I opened myself about this some months ago: [Is the wireless driver from Live USB different from the standard install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137162/is-the-wireless-driver-from-live-usb-different-from-the-standard-install/197296#197296)

Best of luck.