# Why is my internet so slow with an Atheros wireless card?

Tags: 11.04, wireless, drivers, atheros

Since I upgraded from Ubuntu 10.10 to 11.04, my internet connection is as slow as hell. I have tested my other 10.10 machine and it is just as quick as the first one was.

What has happened? Why is the maximum download speed now 30kb/s instead of the 2.5mb/s I used to have?

Comment: We need more details. How are you connected to your ISP? What does `ifconfig` tell you? `route`? Is your `cat /etc/resolv.conf` (nameserver) ok? Only throughput slow, on every protocol, or are there delays; is ping slow too?

Comment: How did you measure the bandwidth? Do you have speedtest results to compare from the two machines?

Comment: My connection sometimes slow down and other times it speeds up. Sometimes it spends a lot "thinking", but the page freezes always reading...

Comment: i think it is Chromium problem... Now i've tryed a while on firefox and WLAN was very quick... gmail without speed problems. Maybe the update that they have done today have some issues or bugs!?

Comment: I've tryed this and it seems to me that my wlan0 connection works better now! I'm still testing, but you can try it too: type sudo iwconfig <return>
note the name of wifi card (example eth1)
type sudo iwconfig [name of card] power off <return>

Now test speed. It appears 11.04 restricts power to Wifi card to save power at the cost of unusable internet!

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel-team/+archive/ppa/+buildjob/2335188 Maybe the help for this issue you can find it here, by downloading (in my case) linux-backports-modules-compat-wireless-2.6.38-2.6.35-28-generic_2.6.35-28.20_amd64.deb (3.1 MiB)  Try yourself and post it here, please.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've found out the problem; it's some sort of problem with my wifi driver (ath9k) which was resolved with a simple command:

```
sudo -s
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

Comment: Report this for the relevant driver package on Launchpad.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I had to upgrade my kernel to 2.6.39. It wasn't hard to do, and I describe how in http://askubuntu.com/questions/29950/wireless-on-an-atheros-ar9285-is-slow-and-disconnects/49649#49649.

Comment: Thanks @Dante it seemed to work for me... What does that line mean anyway ?

Comment: what this conf do under the cover ?

Comment: This worked for me, just do a restart if it doesn't work for you right away.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in 13.04. Results mixed.

Comment: not working in 13.10

Comment: This worked pretty well in 14.04!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but only after upgrade to 11.10. Either way, neither `echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf` (s/9/5 if you're using ath5k) or disabling IPv6 (another solution floating around) helped.

What did help was changing the encryption on the network from WEP to WPA2 (inspired by a forum post I can't find at the moment on a related issue where encryption slowed down a wireless connection). It's still not as speedy as some of my other computers, but a whole lot better than it was.

Comment: This did not work for me as I'm already using wpa2

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the dma64 option helped for rtl8192e

```
echo "options rtl8192ee  dma64=1" >/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8192ee.conf
```