# WiFi too slow with an Atheros AR928X 

Tags: 11.04, wireless, atheros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is my internet so slow with an Atheros wireless card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37409/why-is-my-internet-so-slow-with-an-atheros-wireless-card)

Hey guys!

I've updated my Ubuntu 10.10 and since then, with 11.04, i've notice that my wifi connection is too slow... There's someway to fix this? There's some package to fix this?

Here it is my laptop characteristics:

Acer Aspire 5542G

AMD Turion II X2 M500

ATI Mobility Radeon HD4570

THNX!