# Wi-fi with ath5k - bad connections after idle

Tags: wireless, ath5k, idle, madwifi

I used some older Ubuntu (so I guess it used madwifi), now I installed new Ubuntu 11.10, but I got problem with wifi, it uses ath5k - everything works, downloading etc, but if I stay to read some page for example (facebook messages etc) a then I am trying interact with the page, it does not load. I have to reload whole tab...

so the wifi somehow freeze when is in the idle...

I find several people with the same/similar issue:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=702230
  http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/SuSE/2010-05/msg00880.html

but I did not find solution... I guess I can recompile madwifi, but this I consider as the last option...

my wifi:
Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR5212/AR5213 Multiprotocol MAC/baseband processor (rev 01)

I tried disable ipv6 and install compact wireless drivers, did not help.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Try the [following solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/40692/6642), replacing `ath9k` with `ath5k` (you might need to update your kernel, as someone mentions in the comments)?

I'm not sure, but I think the ath5k has an identical option.

That is:

```
sudo -s
echo "options ath5k nohwcrypt=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/ath5k.conf
```