# Wireless stopped working on a Gateway LT2805u

Tags: wireless, hardware, atheros

Gateway LT2805u Netbook Running Ubuntu 10.04.

Wireless suddenly stopped working. `rfkill` shows no output. And the wireless card shows "Unclaimed".

Card is an **Atheros** (ar9285 i think). My hardware switch is the <kbd>F3</kbd> key but it has no effect.
If I load Ubuntu 11.10 it all seems to work fine, however I would like to stay at 10.04.
Also, I am brand new to Ubuntu so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

It seems many people are having a problem with that wireless card and I could not find a solution that works for everyone.

The most common solution is

```
echo "blacklist acer_wmi" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

Then reboot.

Posted on this blog - http://ubuntulinuxgethelp.com/2012/02/ubuntu-sony-vaio-atheros-ar9285-suddenly-keeps-dropping-wifi-connection/

Same commands are posted on the forums and askubuntu

Example: [Why is my internet so slow with an Atheros wireless card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37409/why-is-my-internet-so-slow-with-an-atheros-wireless-card/40692#40692)

You can also try (you will have to enable the backports repository first).

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-wireless-lucid-generic
```

From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Device/Atheros/AR9285

My advice would be for you to try a more up to date version of Ubuntu as this is goin gto be dependent on the kernel. You may want to try 12.04, and if it does not work, file a bug report.