# Can't connect to wifi after 13.10 update - Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0030] (rev 01)

Tags: wireless, 13.10, atheros

I updated Ubuntu to 13.10 last night and wifi was working fine until I went to wake up my computer this morning and no WiFi connection. I am on a iMac with

```
Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0030] (rev 01).
```

The only solutions I have seen so far are for broadcomm WiFi drivers. There is no wifi driver in addition drivers only graphics drivers.

Not sure how to fix this, Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: WiFi works after reboot but doesn't after being put to sleep nor does Ethernet connect after sleep.

Guess I am going to have to re install ubuntu as I haven't found any fix yet, thanks anyways..

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on my Asus laptop with an Ath9k card, and this seems to have helped me...
[Why is my internet so slow with an Atheros wireless card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37409/why-is-my-internet-so-slow-with-an-atheros-wireless-card#40692)

My problem was that it kept disconnecting during a session.  Also, it's worth noting that the reason there are lots of things about Broadcom and not Atheros is that Atheros has historically worked out of the box with Ubuntu.

Hope that helps you a little at least.