# Wifi keeps dropping to 0kBps

Tags: networking, wireless

I am new to ubuntu. I connected ubuntu to my home network and it just stays at 0kBps or move around a little bit from 0 to 1kBps.

I tried at lot of solutions. None of them seems to work for me.

The weird part is whenever i try to open a webpage it takes 20-30 seconds before i could see a real development but speedtest.net open instantly and the speed test shows i have 2MBps connection.

I am using SYstem Monitor app from app store to check network speed. The time the test is running, speed jumps to 2MBps and then suddenly drops to 0 after the test is finished.

Please help guys.

```
sudo lshw -class network gives
*-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 74:2f:68:b6:e4:5f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.16.0-50-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.106 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:ddc00000-ddc0ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 06
       serial: 54:04:a6:12:e6:9a
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:46 ioport:9000(size=256) memory:d2104000-d2104fff memory:d2100000-d2103fff
```

Comment: Does anything else on your home network have this issue as well?

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/37409/why-is-my-internet-so-slow-with-an-atheros-wireless-card/40692#40692

Comment: No...my desktop and cell phone works fine. I have dual booted the system. The other os is window 10 which seems to be working fine as well.