# What can I do about rsync of large files killing my laptop's wifi connection

Tags: wireless, rsync, atheros

When I run a rsync to backup my home folder over the network like so:

```
rsync -avhz --progress --delete /home/dbdean/ david@tv.local:/home/backups/david/
```

I seem to have problems with my quite large `.VirtualBox/HardDisks/Windows XP.vdi` file. Occasionally the wifi will silently fail (the transfer stops, and any other network access is broken). If I reconnect the wifi to my network before the transfer times out, it happily keeps going (and other network access is back), but I can't just leave it unattended most of the time, as I have to keep an eye on it.

I'm guessing this is probably a bug in the wireless card related to a particularly high sustained volume of network usage, but I'm not really sure where to start with diagnosing this problem so that I can provide a good bug report. Or it could be something else, I guess. Any help would be appreciated.

My network card is an Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285, as `lspci -k` shows:

```
43:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3040
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't the wireless router that is dropping the connection? Have you checked the logs?

Comment: yeah, because reconnecting the wireless on the laptop fixes it, and no-one else loses access.

Comment: What kind of wifi card (try `lspci | grep Ethernet`)? I'm seeing this with an Atheros AR9285 card (in a laptop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using an Atheros wifi card on Natty? If so, try upgrading your Linux kernel to 2.6.39. See my answer on [Wireless on an Atheros AR9285 is slow and disconnects](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29950/wireless-on-an-atheros-ar9285-is-slow-and-disconnects/49649#49649) for more information.

Comment: I am. I'll have a go at upgrading my kernel and give you a tick if it fixes it. Thanks!

Comment: It seems you are right. Kernel 2.6.39 fixes the problem.

Comment: David Dean: right on! Will you also consider [trying out 2.6.38-10.44](https://bugs.launchpad.net/null/+bug/799609/comments/3)?

Answer (score 3):

I think because rsync use all bandwidth in wifi **CMIIW**, you must limit rsync banwidth usage so other proccess still work. try to add  -*-bwlimit* parameter, then your script will be like this :

> rsync -avhz --bwlimit 10 --progress
>   --delete /home/dbdean/ david@tv.local:/home/backups/david/