# cannot use only external LCD monitor with laptop

Tags: 11.04, unity, gnome, monitor

I just bought a new laptop. I like to connect it to an external monitor, and configure the displays such that the laptop screen is off, and the external monitor is set to max resolution.

When I do make this change in the displays/monitors configuration, both displays go dark. After the "keep settings?" timeout expires, only the mouse cursor is visible.

The laptop is a http://zareason.com/shop/Strata-Pro-13.html. It has Intel GMA 4500MHD integrated video.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 (natty). This problem repros in Unity and GNOME Shell. Repros with
both VGA and HDMI outputs. **Does not** repro in Ubuntu 10.04.2, so it makes me suspect some kernel problem in Ubuntu 11.04.

**Update (Mon Jun 20 02:19:33 UTC 2011):**

- Kernel is 2.6.38-8-generic-pae (32-bit). Problem also repros on non-PAE 32-bit kernel.
- lsmod shows the "i915" driver is loaded and "video" is using it, so I'm guessing the video driver in use is "i915".
- I filed a bug in launchpad, too: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/799609

Comment: It's probably not the _kernel_ per se, but more likely the video driver.  Which driver (and version) are you using in 11.04 and 10.04.2?

Comment: Does any of the display comes back online after the timeout ?

Comment: Flimzy: i915, based on lsmod output. The kernel version is 2.6.38-8-generic-pae (32-bit). Also repros with non-PAE kernel.

Comment: Capt.Nemo: just the cursor. But I *can* use CTRL-ALT-F1 to switch to a virtual terminal and `pkill X`, and then X restarts, I see the login screen and can log back into X.

Comment: Flimzy: Not sure what kernel was being used with 10.04.2... whatever comes in the distro download right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading my Linux kernel to 2.6.39 fixed the problem.

I describe an easy way to do this in [Wireless on an Atheros AR9285 is slow and disconnects](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29950/wireless-on-an-atheros-ar9285-is-slow-and-disconnects/49649#49649) (another issue I had with the kernel that came with Natty).