# Is the wireless driver from Live USB different from the standard install?

Tags: wireless, atheros

Linux newbie here. I've been trying to use Ubuntu (x64) as my main OS since 11.10, but my wireless connection on it has been very unstable, droping every other 5-10 mins. For this reason I see myself forced to use Windows 7 (dual booting), where connection works flawlessly -- which really bothers me.

My card is an Atheros 9k, which claims a reasonable amount of wireless complaints on Ubuntu forums. I've tried every suggestion given on past questions to this site but to no avail. However, while running Ubuntu Live USB for some of the tests, I noticed that my wireless connection never failed on it and wondered if its network configuration differs from the one on the default Ubuntu install. If this is the case, how could I reproduce the Live USB network environment on my hard drive install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that, after a long struggle with Ubuntu over my internet connection, I found that switching from Unity to Gnome 3 solved the issue. I guess both interfaces use different network managers and Gnome's one keeps connection stable.

I mark this answer as accepted since it eliminates the issue. If a more precise/detailed one comes up (i.e. instructions to install Gnome's network manager into Unity) from a more experienced user, I'll choose it.

Answer (score 0):

Linux newbie here too. In my option, if you install ubuntu to your hard disk, the possible thing may affect is the upgrade of the kernel, since you may upgrade routinely, the newest kernel may somewhat has issues.

Using Live CD, ubuntu use the default released kernel, which in your case may act good performance to your wireless network card. For further investigation, the best way is to re-compile or add the best responding module of your wireless adapter in, which may out of my knowledge :D

In general, if you feel it's stable to use the kernel shipped with the Live CD/USB, just copy them out and replace the kernel on your hard disk (in /boot folder).

Hope it helps.